# Understanding hex representation of binary file

Tags: binary, hex, binaryfiles, hexdump

I need some help understanding the format of looking at a binary file in hex so I get get the correct numbers out of a table using python to parse it

Example:

```
0000b50: 0400 0000 ffff 0900 0000 ffff 0900 0000 ................
0000b60: ffff 0900 0000 ffff 0900 0000 ffff 0900 ............0..@
```

When I need to find the start of an object at index `0x0b54` where would that be? Would it be **[here]**? `0000b50: 0400 [0]000 ffff 0900 0000 ffff 0900 0000`

The object is 96 bytes long. is one set of four hex numbers one byte? ie. `ffff`? or since it is base 16 each individual spot contains 2 bytes? so `ffff` is 8 bytes? And I need to find 6 bytes for each entry into the table which would be `fff`?

What does the part at the end represent? ie. `............0..@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f = 16 = 1111 so ff is 16x16 = 11111111 = 256 = one 8 bit byte. 
ffff = 2 bytes.
You need to translate the numbers into binary to figure out the byte count.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out a while ago, because I needed to for a project at work, but I wanted someone else to leave an answer here